# delete vs delete[] in destructor

Tags: c++, oop

I study for an exam in c++
and I was asked if in this code the d'tor of the class should use delete[] instead delete:

```
    template <class T>
class ClonePtr
{
private:
    T* ptr;
public:
    explicit ClonePtr(T* p = nullptr) : ptr(p) {}
    ~ClonePtr() { if(ptr!=nullptr) delete []ptr; }
    ClonePtr(const ClonePtr& other) : ptr(nullptr)
    {
        *this = other;
    }
    ClonePtr(ClonePtr&& other) : ptr(other.ptr)
    {
        other.ptr = nullptr;
    }
    ClonePtr& operator=(const ClonePtr& other)
    {
        if (this != &other)
        {
            delete ptr;
            if (other.ptr != nullptr)
                ptr = other.ptr->clone();
        }
        return *this;
    }
    T& operator*() const { return *ptr; }
};
```

The right answer to the question is yes,
but why is that?

+I have two more little question regarding this code:

1. It says in the exam that type T must be a class and cannot be a primitve type.
   Why is that?
2. On the other hand, I tried writing this code:

```
class A
{
private:
    int x;
public:
    A(int x = 8) : x(x) { };
};

int main()
{
    ClonePtr<int> h(new A(7));
}
```

and got a compiler error: C2664 "cannot convert argument 1 from A* to T*"

I will very much appreciate your help.

thanks :)

Comment: This is a terrible class. It doesn't allocate any memory, why would it delete memory, much less know to `delete[]`.

Comment: There is no indication of allocating an array.  Thus use `delete` not `delete []`.  The `delete[]` is for deleting arrays.

Comment: Is the `delete ptr` in `operator=` intentional? If that were the case, and the question was specifically about the destructor, I would say it should be `delete` (to match the other one).

Comment: This is actually a beautiful example of why you should reject `new` and `delete`, whether they are the `[]` version or not,  and stick to containers and smart pointers. Unless you know exactly how something was allocated, because you allocated it or the provider's documentation sell you how to dispose of it, you shouldn't try to release it. It could have been `malloc`ed or automatically allocated for all you know.

Comment: `ClonePtr<int>` will specialize around `int`. this means `ClonePtr(T* p = nullptr)` will become `ClonePtr(int* p = nullptr)`. and want a pointer to `int`, not a pointer to `A`. `ClonePtr<A>` will accept a pointer to `A`.

Comment: The exam question is improper. There is insufficient information provided to answer it.

Comment: @sharon If this is what the exam is teaching you, then you should find a better class to attend. This exam is not doing you any good.

Comment: Just the fact that there is an `if (ptr!=nullptr)` check in the destructor is a bad sign.  There is no need to check for `nullptr` when issuing a calling to `delete` or `delete[]`.

Answer (score 5):

There is no way for us to answer this definitely one way or the other, because we can't see what kind of pointer is being passed to `ClonePtr(T*)`, or what kind of pointer is being returned by `clone()`.  This class is not doing any memory allocations of its own.

*IF* both pointers are being allocated with `new` and not by `new[]`, then `delete` would be the correct answer, not `delete[]`.

*IF* both pointers are being allocated with `new[]` and not by `new`, then `delete[]` would be the correct answer, not `delete`.

For that matter, since this code is *taking ownership* of memory allocated by something else, and it is clear by this class' use of `nullptr` and a move constructor (but not a move assignment operator!) that you are using C++11 or later, so you *should* be utilizing *proper* ownership semantics via `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`, not using a raw pointer at all.

Especially since your copy assignment operator is not setting `ptr` to `nullptr` after `delete ptr;` if `other.ptr` is `nullptr`, leaving `*this` in a bad state.  Using proper ownership semantics would have avoided that.

Try this instead:

---

**UPDATE:** now you have posted additional code (that doesn't compile, since an `A*` can't be assigned to an `int*`, and `A` does not implement `clone()`) showing `ptr` being set to an object allocated with `new`, so the correct answer is:

- `delete` MUST be used, not `delete[]`.

So the "right answer" to your exam is wrong.

But proper ownership semantics would be even better, eg:

```
#include <memory>

template <class T>
class ClonePtr
{
private:
    std::unique_ptr<T> ptr;

public:
    ClonePtr(std::unique_ptr<T> p) : ptr(std::move(p)) {}

    ClonePtr& operator=(ClonePtr other)
    {
        ptr = std::move(other.ptr);
        return *this;
    }

    T& operator*() const { return *ptr; }
};

class A
{
private:
    int x;

public:
    A(int x = 8) : x(x) { };

    std::unique_ptr<A> clone() const
    {
        return std::make_unique<A>(x);
        // or: prior to C++14:
        // return std::unique_ptr<A>(new A(x));
    }
};

int main()
{
    ClonePtr<A> h(std::make_unique<A>(7));
    // or, prior to C++14:
    // ClonePtr<A> h(std::unique_ptr<A>(new A(7)));
}
```

Comment: I also thought this exam is lacking of information...
I thought it is not possible to answer the question which delete we should use if we don't know if the pointer points to a single object or to an array..
Weird question. Thanks though :)

Comment: by the way, do you by any chance know why this class can only receive a class as T and not a primitive type?

Comment: Surely primitive types would be rejected as they cannot possibly implement `clone`, whereas a class could.

Comment: @Tas good point. Though, the call to `clone()` can be SFINAE'ed away using [`std::is_trivially_copyable()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivially_copyable) so primitive types can be copied as-is and not cloned.